# Centering and Scaling Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: statistics, vectorization, pyspark

I am trying to implement normalization of 5 features in a spark dataframe.
All features have different scales.

In theory, Is it correct to use Normalizer() on a vectorized form of my dataframe?
The other options are MinMaxScaler() and StandardScaler(). However, after going through various implementations I am not confident if I should be using it on each column or the vectorized dataframe.

Welcome any advise.

Comment: What are the types you use ? Do you mean by *vectoized form of my dataframe* that you use `denseVectors` ? Or you have standard columns in your pyspark dataframe ?

Comment: I use vectorize form of my standard dataframe. Specifically, VectorAssembler() @linog

Comment: I have something like this: ```|[17.0,3.0,3.0,1.0,1592.0] |
|[62.0,3.0,4.0,1.0,1592.0]``` Then I am using ```normalizer = Normalizer(inputCol="features", outputCol="normFeatures", p=1.0)
l1NormData = normalizer.transform(output_dat)``` Just need clarity if I am normalizing all columns correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used a `VectorAssembler()`, your data are in the good format to be normalized/rescaled.

You have different types of transformations possible. They will create different distributions of the values within your vectors. I take the examples from this [post](https://medium.com/@dhiraj.p.rai/essentials-of-feature-engineering-in-pyspark-part-i-76a57680a85).

The question is now: which distribution makes sense for you afterward ? Do you want a N(0,1) distribution ? In that case, use `StandardScaler`.

## `StandardScaler`

Each `i`th element of your vectors are transformed by removing mean and dividing by standard deviation of all `i`th rows.

```py
+---+--------------+------------------------------------------------
|id |features      |Scaled_features|
+---+--------------+------------------------------------------------
|0  |[1.0,0.1,-1.0]|[1.195228,0.02337,-0.597614]|
|1  |[2.0,1.1,1.0] |[2.390457,0.25713,0.597614]   |
|0  |[1.0,0.1,-1.0]|[1.19522,0.023376,-0.5976143046671968]|
|1  |[2.0,1.1,1.0] |[2.390457,0.257138,0.597614]   |
|1  |[3.0,10.1,3.0]|[3.585682.3609991,1.792842]  |
+---+--------------+------------------------------------------------
```

Given the title of your question, I think this is the operation you want to perform.

## `Normalizer`

You normalize the `i`th value by a norm computed from all dimensions. Most commons are Manhattan norm (norm L1, the one you used) and Euclidean norm (norm L2).

[image]

So you divide each value by the norm computed

```py
+---+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|id |features      |l1_norm                    |
+---+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|0  |[1.0,0.1,-1.0]|[0.47619,0.047619,-0.47619]|
|1  |[2.0,1.1,1.0] |[0.48780,0.26829,0.24390]  |
|0  |[1.0,0.1,-1.0]|[0.47619,0.047619,-0.47619]|
|1  |[2.0,1.1,1.0] |[0.48780,0.26829,0.24390]  |
|1  |[3.0,10.1,3.0]|[0.18633,0.62732,0.18633]  |
+---+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Here, `[1,.1,-1]/sum(abs([1,.1,-1]))` -> `[0.47619,0.047619,-0.47619]`

## MinMaxScaler

You change the interval of your values to fit into a `[a,b]` interval

## An example

Let's say, you have `[10 000, 1, 1, 1]`:

- `Normalizer`: with L1 norm, `[0.9997, 9.997001e-05 9.997001e-05 9.997001e-05]`
- `StandardScaler`: assuming you substract mean and divide by sd, you end up with `[1.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5]`.

You end up with very different distributions because you don't weight the extreme values the same way

Comment: please correct me if I misinterpreted. So, one of my columns has huge numbers (1-10000), all other 4 are in the range (1-10). You are saying that vectorization followed by Normalizer (Manhattan, L1) takes care of this.

Comment: I edited the answer. Yes it will rescale your 10k number.

Comment: So, just to get your opinion, how does the Normalizer make sense. Because lets say I run a PCA ultimately. I am ending up with a very high coefficient for the variable with '10000'. Note: Just trying NOT to massage the data too much.

Comment: As the 5 variables are in different range/units, a Normalizer simply distributes the values based on distance over all variables in a single vector ```[10 000, 1, 1, 1]```. Moreover, I feel it does that horizontally, which does not make sense to me.

Comment: Clearly, you don't want too much heterogeneity in the variance of your variables with PCA. I would rather go in `StandardScaler` in that case

Comment: If you think your question has been answered, don't forget to accept it :) [see guidelines if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)